# and/or with 3 cells

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I have succeed in making `R3C18` read **true** if data in `C10`, and **false** if data in `C19` with:

`=IF(OR(RC[-8]<1,(RC[1])>1),FALSE, TRUE)`

How can I have `C9` **true** with data in `C1`, but only if no data is entered in `C10` or `C19`?

[image: Excel Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an `AND` statement combined with `OR`

Like so: `=IF(AND(RC[-8]<>"",OR(RC[1]="",RC[10]="")),TRUE,FALSE)`

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(AND(RC[-8]>1,OR(RC[1]<1,RC[10]<1)),True, false)`

If you want to have both `C10` AND `C19` blank in order to return a true you can use:

`=IF(AND(RC[-8]>1,RC[1]<1,RC[10]<1),True, false)`